# Unix Domain Socket (C++) - Client crashes server daemon

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, unix

I've got quite a problem.
I recently started in daemon and socket programming. My current setup consists out of a daemon that creates a socket and a client that writes messages and reads the processed answer.
Well, *should* read the answer.

The daemon daemonizes itself, creates the socket and even processes the message (I can verify via log entries I make) but as soon as I try to send the answer to the client the daemon is blocked; the client never receives an answer and if I `ctrl-c` the client the daemon is shutdown too.
This is totally strange behaviour to me and I can't explain what happens which is why I'm asking you on any hints.

Brief summary:
 - the socket type is `AF_UNIX`, therefore local and no networking involved
 - the daemon successfully receives the message, but can not write back
 - the client can not read (because `send()` of the server is blocking) and
if I `ctrl-c` the client the daemon quits too (but that signal does not get sent to the daemon)

Below is my code, stripped down to the interesting and not working part.
Many thanks in advance for hints, help and suggestions!

**UPDATE:**

Added the client code as well!

```
int main()
{
    //those two work just fine
    createSocket();
    daemonize();

    //declare some variables needed in the big loop
    FILE *client_fd;
    int fd;
    socklen_t len;
    string tmp;
    char *buf = new char[1024];
    while(1)
    {
        struct sockaddr_un saun;
        len = sizeof(saun);

        //receive an fd for the incoming connection
        if((fd = accept(m_socket, (sockaddr*)&saun, &len)) < 0)
        {
            writeLog("Accepting connection failed!");
            continue;
        }
        //i wanted to use fgets, therefore obtain a FILE object here
        client_fd = fdopen(fd, "r");
        if(client_fd == NULL)
        {
            writeLog("fdopen() failed!");
            continue;
        }
        while(fgets(buf, bufferSize, client_fd) != NULL)
        {
            //message read succeeds (verified)
            writeLog(buf);
            tmp = evaluateMsg(buf);

            //tmp is not empty (verified)
            writeLog(tmp);

            //send seems to block, nothing happens from now on
            //I don't even get in one of the if-else branches
            if(send(fd, (tmp + "\n").c_str(), tmp.size() + 1, 0) < 0)
            {
                writeLog("Could not write message back!");
                continue;
            }
            else
                writeLog("bytes written!");
        }
        close(fd);
    }
}
```

Following is the client code:

```
int main()
{
    int sockfd;
    sockaddr_un addr;

    sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(addr.sun_path, SOCKET_PATH);

    //the connection is successfull
    if(connect(sockfd, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        cerr<<"Connection failed!"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    //message is written successfully
    write(sockfd, "hello", 5);
    char *buf = new char[1024];

    //same as for the server, I wanted to use fgets
    //therefore need to obtain a FILE object
    FILE *fd = fdopen(sockfd, "r");
    fgets(buf, 1024, fd);
    cout<<buf<<endl;

    close(sockfd);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the client code as well. It just looks like that client is actually not reading the data from socket, blocking the server.

Comment: Sure, sorry I forgot...

Comment: Hi Mäx, we don't put answers in questions here. (And don't put tags like "solved" in titles either.) You should post your answer/solution as an answer to your question. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, will do!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found the solution myself.

The problem was the (convenient) call to `fgets()`; I had to use `read()` and now everything works like a charm.
I'm not sure why `read()` is mandatory, but I assume it's got to do with the buffer, which is emptied as far as it's read...
But that's only my assumption!